# how to handle vector as element in data frame? [R]

Tags: r, vector, dataframe, element

How do I store a few numbers in one element of data frame? 
For example I want a summary of my data, including the class and values in each column.

```
dat = data.frame(STATE = 1:5,
                 MONTH = 1:5)
```

should yield:

```
var       class    values
STATE    numeric   c(1,2,3,4,5)
MONTH    numeric   c(1,2,3,4,5)
```

Now I try:

```
dat = data.frame(STATE = 1:5,
                 MONTH = 1:5)

vars = data.frame(var = colnames(dat), class = NA, values = NA,
                  stringsAsFactors = F)
vars$class = sapply(dat, class)

vars
#      var   class values
# 1  STATE integer     NA
# 2  MONTH integer     NA

vars$values = sapply(dat, function(x) unique(x))
# Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "values", value = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L,  : 
#                replacement has 5 rows, data has 2

# UPDATE: @jMathew 's answer:
vars$values = sapply(dat, function(x) list(unique(x)))
vars
# var   class        values
# 1 STATE integer 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
# 2 MONTH integer 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

It doesn't work because unique(dat$STATE) = c(1,2,3,4,5), and R thinks it should be 5 elements in data frame, and can't fit in one element.

But the above code works for many data sets I work with, e.g.:

```
library(foreign)
dat = read.xport('LLCP2013.XPT')
# download from http://www.cdc.gov/brfss/annual_data/2013/files/LLCP2013XPT.ZIP

dat = dat[1:5, 1:3]
dat
# X_STATE FMONTH    IDATE
# 1       1      1 01092013
# 2       1      1 01192013
# 3       1      1 01192013
# 4       1      1 01112013
# 5       1      2 02062013

vars = data.frame(var = colnames(dat), class = NA, values = NA,
                  stringsAsFactors = F)
vars$class = sapply(dat, class)
vars$values = sapply(dat, function(x) unique(x))
vars
# var   class         values
# 1 X_STATE numeric              1
# 2  FMONTH numeric           1, 2
# 3   IDATE  factor 16, 36, 20, 70

# UPDATE:
class(vars[3,3]) 
# [1] "list"
# @jMathew was right, it was somehow coerced to list
```

Can somebody tells me why this works in the second case but not in the first? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that in your second case, the vector is being coerced to a `list`
Try, this on your first example

```
vars$values = sapply(dat, function(x) list(unique(x)))
```

Answer (score 1):

We could try

```
do.call(rbind,lapply(seq_along(dat), function(i) 
       data.frame(var=names(dat)[i], class=class(dat[,i]), 
         values= sprintf('c(%s)', toString(unique(dat[,i]))))))
#    var   class           values
#1 STATE integer c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
#2 MONTH integer c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```